# Index out of range error when trying to access the last index

Tags: python, index-error

I am doing leetcode and my code is giving me this error that I can't make sense of.  I am asked to reverse the integer, which is fairly simple to do.  These are the test cases:

```
Example 1:

Input: 123
Output: 321

Example 2:

Input: -123
Output: -321

Example 3:

Input: 120
Output: 21
```

I figured that all I need were if-statements to check the condition of the input so here is what I did:

```
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        string = str(x)
        lst = list(string)

        lst.reverse()

        if((lst[0]) == '0'):
            lst.pop(0)

        if((lst[-1] == '-')):
            lst.pop(-1)
            lst.insert(0, '-')

        output = ''.join(lst)

        return output
```

But this line `if((lst[-1] == '-')):` is throwing an `IndexError: list index out of range` error.  All I'm doing is accessing the last element of the list.  I am not trying to access an index which doesn't exist.

The only thing that I need to know is why this error is happening.  Because this is leetcode, I'd like to fix the code myself.

**Final Code**

```
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        lst = list(str(x))

        lst.reverse()

        if(x < 0):
            lst.pop(-1)
            lst.insert(0, '-')

        int_output = int(''.join(lst))

        if(int_output < (2**32)):
            return int_output
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: check first `if lst:` to see if list is not empty. Or both `if lst and lst[-1] == '-':`

Comment: Please Sie input that triggers that condition. Are you perhaps dealing with the string 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error will happen if `lst` is empty, since any index will be out of range.

If `x` was originally `"0"`, then `lst` will be `["0"]`. The first `if` statement will then remove the `"0"` element, so now it will be `[]`, which is an empty list, and you'll get that error.

If you're doing [7. Reverse Integer](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/) you have other problems. It says that the result should be an integer, but you're returning a string. You also only remove the first `0`. If the input is `12000` you'll return `"0021"` instead of `21`.

Comment: So right after the reversal and replacing the - symbol, all I gotta do is convert it back to an int, right?  That takes care of the leading zeros.

Comment: There is an error with LeetCode as well as it is not accepting some reversals.  Check my up to date code if you like.  I've given you an upvote and accepted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, do you mind giving me an upvote?

Comment: The range check at the end should be `if -2**32 <= int_output < 2**32:`